# TSQL max value from stored procedure results most efficient way

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to determine the max value of an object based on the values of sub objects.

```
exec GetSubObjects @ID = ID
```

yields a result set of sub objects with an int for status

I need the highest status from that result set.

is there a way to do an aggregate on the results set straight away?

Comment: What is the return type of GetSubObjects?  If it is a table you can use it in a from clause.

Comment: just a result set, are you thinking using OUTPUT?

Answer (score 1):

You could use TABLE variable and insert results there

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    COL1 INT
)

INSERT INTO @t
exec GetSubObjects @ID = ID
```

then you have results in table so you can do anything you like

```
SELECT MAX(COL1) FROM @T
```

Comment: that's pretty much what I got to.  I did some research on not having to define the table var/temp table, seems like mixed reviews on using OPENROWSET (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure).

Comment: I now have a problem in that what I'm ultimately trying to get is a result set of the outer objects with the status of each object based that select max.  A function makes sense, but it seems you can't run the exec inside a function...